# Dual boot linux/windows online/offline configuration

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot

Does anyone have any tip for setting up a desktop workstation configuration with a linux drive for web activities and a windows drive for other personal purposes?

Thanks in advance :)

And sorry if the question does not belong to this category.

Comment: It might be worth considering using a Virtual Machine, so that you can run both environments simultaneously. Make the native OS the one where you need better performance and install the other as the VM.

Comment: I see. I'd have windows (need specific softwares and gpu support) with a Linux VM for browsing. Is it then enough to uninstall Windows network card to isolate the OS? Will the VM still be able to connect to internet?

Comment: I doubt it, but I've never tried. However, you should be able to disconnect internet access from Windows while leaving it open to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

If you use VMware, you can disconnect a USB network card from the host machine and attach it to the virtual machine. However, you can't disconnect the built in card from windows and attach it to the VM, because VMware uses the built in card to manage internet connectivity for all its virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtualbox, much more user friendly than VMware IMO. Just install linux inside it, and run it while you are in Winblows. That way you have access to both OSes at once! :)

Comment: Well the idea is to keep the two environments apart isolating windows from internet for security purporses and having Linux for internet to be less vulnerable. And no, Windows in a VM is not a good option because I need to use the hardware at full capacity. :) I wondered if there's something more to think about on such configuration.

Comment: I meant Linux in a vm, they are still relatively isolated, besides for low low level stuff, and you wouldn't catch as many virii using your Linux vm for internet. Linux doesn't suck as much performance, especially if you use one with xfce or another lightweight environment.